# A layout overlapping a RecyclerView and this RecyclerView is still clickable on top of the layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with certain elements added. Every time I click on one of the elements, a layout becomes visible in the same view with the element's data. The problem is that when the new layout becomes visible, you can keep pressing the recyclerview that is below.

This is my app:

[image]

When I click an element, it make visible a layout with the info of the element clicked:

[image]

If I click the new visible layout and an element of the recyclerView is behind it, the click of the new Layout works

What I want to do is that once the new layout is visible, you cannot click the elements below by clicking on the layout, only if you click on the element directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `rootView` of your `layout` which is coming on to screen `clickable` and `focusable` there by it will intercept touch events in hierarchy and would not pass it to `recycler`.

```
<RootViewGroup
 ...
 android:clickable = "true"
 android:focusable = "true"
/>
```

Comment: Can you make a little sample? I never used RootViewGroup